# Is it possible for $f(z)$ and $f(\sigma z)$ to both be Hecke eigenfunctions?

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms, hecke-algebras

Let $f(z)$ be an automorphic/modular form on $\Gamma_0(p)/\mathbb{H}$, where $p$ is some prime.

I know that the Hecke operators $T_n$ act on this space of functions whenever $(n,p)=1$.

Assume that $f(z)$ is a Hecke eigenforms for all $T_n$ with $(n,p)=1$, is it plausible that there exists a $\sigma\in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $f(\sigma z)$ would also be a Hecke eigenform for all $T_n$ with $(n,p)=1$, and, of course $\sigma \not\in \Gamma_0(p)$.

(I understand that $f(Sz)$ is not automorphic for $\Gamma_0(p)/\mathbb{H}$.)

Comment: $f$ any level $1$ cusp eigenform. Then what is $\sigma$, do we have $\sigma^{-1}\Gamma_0(p)\sigma=\Gamma_0(p)$. And when $f$ is a weight $k$ level $p$ newform what can you say about $z^{-k}f(-1/z)$.

Comment: Yeah, I am not so interested in the level 1 case, more in the newform case. I am not sure what one could say about $z^{-k}f(-1/z)$.

Comment: Over $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})/\mathbb{H}$ the Hecke operators $T_n$ are defined generally as a summation over a unique member of each orbit of the action of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ on the set of matrices of determinant $n$. As operators on $\Gamma_0(p)/\mathbb{H}$, the operators must specify the representative too. Then a left shift by $\sigma\in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ changes the set of representatives.

Comment: There are plenty of textbooks on modular forms. For level $p$ we look at the action of $\Gamma_0(p)$ instead of $SL_2(\Bbb{Z})$.

Comment: I know, my research in the topic has led me to consider the action of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ on forms of level $p$. Thank you very much anyways.

Comment: This happens naturally when trying to understand the behaviour of a form of level $p$ at the cusp in 0 by changing coordinates.

Comment: $f(\sigma z)$ is a $\sigma^{-1}\Gamma_0(p)\sigma$ modular form not a $\Gamma_0(p)$ modular form. There are Hecke operators for $\sigma^{-1}\Gamma_0(p)\sigma$ (just conjugate by $\sigma$ the $\Gamma_0(p)$ operators), this is one of the ideas of automorphic forms.

Comment: For a newform (of level dividing $p$) we know the effect of $f\to f(-1/z)$ (thanks to the Fricke involution) and $g\to g(z+a/b)$ amounts to replacing $g$ by a sum of $\sum_n a_n(g) \chi(n) e^{2i\pi nz}$. Composing the two we know the effect of any $\sigma\in SL_2(\Bbb{Z})$ on the Fourier coefficients at $i\infty$.

Comment: I couldn't have imagined a more helpful comment. The Fricke involution is exactly what I have been searching for.